# SUBSTRING And CHARINDEX to separate values in a column

Tags: t-sql

I have a column in my database that stores title, first name and last name. But data in this column is not clean as sometimes, the customer's title is missing or null, other time the first name is not available and some other time, the last name is void. Now, I want to separate or split the column into three - Title, FirstName, LastName bearing in mind that I have to check for nulls or empty data. How do I clean this data so that errors like:

```
Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.
```

or

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

are not returned.

I wrote a script like this but not good enough.

```
SELECT FullName
     , LEFT(FullName, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) - 1, -1), LEN(FullName))) AS Title
     , RIGHT(Salute, LEN(Salute) - CHARINDEX(' ', FullName, 1)) FirstName
     , SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName, 19) - 1) LastName
FROM Details
```

If we have a title and a name, we should split into Title, FirstName. If no title, we will treat it as FirstName and LastName
Thank you.

Comment: Null data can't exist in a string.  So what does some of the data look like that represents each of your cases.  You're after a level of pattern matching here.  If Title and firstName are missing, how would you know that it's a last name instead of a first name?  is it separated consistently by a value such as a COMMA? so it may look like ,,Smith or Mr,,Smith or could you have Mr,Smith in which case I don't know if Smith is a last or first name?

Comment: No COMMA or things like that. Data are entered without delimiters.

Comment: So youre using spaces to denote seperation then and assuming names or titles are not compounded such as Jake II or Mr John Paul Jones.

Comment: Yes! Nothing as such.

Comment: You can't do it without making some assumptions.  if we assume only 1 value is entered, we will treat it as last name if we assume 2 values are entered we assume first and last name.  if we assume 3 values are entered then we assume title, first and last names.

Comment: The root of the reason it can't be cleanly done is there's no way to distinguish when Title and First Name exist vs First Name and Last Name, or Title and Last name.  Without a way to "KNOW" what data is present in full name, we have to make assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my best work but:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f87e8/18/0  appears to work given the rules identified in comments.  if the rules change it should be  matter of moving around existing code in the cases to meet the needs.

```
Select FullName, 
CASE len(fullname) - len(replace(fullName,' ','')) 
WHEN 2 then
  LEFT(FULLNAME,charIndex(' ',FULLNAME))
WHEN 1 then
     ''  
when 0 then 
     '' 
end as Title,

CASE len(fullname) - len(replace(fullName,' ','')) 
WHEN 2 then
     REPLACE(REPLACE(FULLNAME,LEFT(FULLNAME,charIndex(' ',FULLNAME)),''),REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(FULLNAME),CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName)))),'')
WHEN 1 then
  LEFT(FULLNAME,CHARINDEX(' ', FullName))   
when 0 then 
     '' 
end as First,

CASE len(fullname) - len(replace(fullName,' ','')) 
WHEN 2 then
       REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(FULLNAME),CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName))))
When 1 then
       REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(FULLNAME),CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName))))   
WHEN 0 then 
       FullName
end as LAST
from foo
```

Comment: Beautiful! This works very very well. Thank you xQbert

Answer (score 0):

Take close look at this

```
RIGHT(Salute, LEN(Salute) - CHARINDEX(' ', FullName, 1)) FirstName
```

Can you see how

> CHARINDEX(' ', FullName, 1)

might be out of range on Salute

```
set nocount on;        
declare @fullname char(200) = 'jonnywalker whiskey     ';
declare @left int;
set @left = (select ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @fullname) - 1, -1), LEN(@fullname)));
select @left;
select LEFT(@fullname, @left) AS Title

declare @salute char(200) = 'salute     ';
declare @right int;
set @right = (select (LEN(@salute) - CHARINDEX(' ', @fullname, 1)));
select @right;
select RIGHT(@salute, @right) FirstName;
```

Comment: Thanks. But the above query gave an error:

    Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 23
    Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: @dLight Exactly. It shows you where the error is.  You cannot see Can you see how CHARINDEX(' ', FullName, 1) might be out of range on Salute?